# How can I set a default profile for a network interface in network manager?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, network-manager

I have the following network profiles defined in Network Manager in my Xubuntu VM:

[image: Network Connections]

"DHCP" and "Static" are bound to `eth1`, and "VM Network" is bound to `eth0`. I'd like "DHCP" to be the default for `eth1`, but NetworkManager always seems to choose the Static profile on startup. How do I set the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you edit the connection you should see *connect automatically* at the top (my screenshot is from Ubuntu, but the functionality should be the same)

[image: screenshot]

Check that checkbox for **the one** connection you want as default.

Comment: Thanks, they were both checked... You'd think this would be an either-or thing.